# 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'EM'

Tags: python, opencv

I am getting the above error.
I Already installed opencv-contrib module but still not working out

```
def dictionary(descriptors, N):
em = cv2.EM(N)
em.train(descriptors)
```

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "", line 1, in 
    runfile('C:/Users/Ankuran Das/Desktop/Pyhton/Case/fishvec.py', wdir='C:/Users/Ankuran Das/Desktop/Pyhton/Case')

File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 827, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

File "C:/Users/Ankuran Das/Desktop/Pyhton/Case/fishvec.py", line 141, in 
    gmm = generate_gmm(working_folder,args.number)

File "C:/Users/Ankuran Das/Desktop/Pyhton/Case/fishvec.py", line 87, in generate_gmm
    means, covs, weights = dictionary(words, N)

File "C:/Users/Ankuran Das/Desktop/Pyhton/Case/fishvec.py", line 16, in dictionary
    em = cv2.EM.train(N)

AttributeError: module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'EM'

Comment: Can you show us how you import cv2?

Comment: Also just in case, try: pip install --force-reinstall opencv-contrib-python

Comment: I have imported cv2 as -  import math, cv2

Comment: Could you edit your question to show the import and the full error traceback please

Comment: yeah ...done ..can you please check now.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following lines of codes:

```
em = cv2.ml.EM_create()
em.setClustersNumber(N)
em.trainEM(descriptors)
```